# how to make external disk mounted executable?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, file-permissions

I'm new to Linux and running on Ubuntu 12.04. I have a windows partition mounted to it but the problem is I can't run executable files (I can't use ./ on a file in that partition). How do I correct this?

EDIT: It was a nfts partition on windows and mount command gives following info.

> /dev/sda3 on /media/Sam type fuseblk
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)

Comment: Partition type? Filesystem type? Any information other than ubuntu 12.04 would be of great help.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30243/why-does-ubuntu-refuse-to-execute-files-from-an-ntfs-partition